# netty tcp endpoint in camel (make "To" end point as tcp socket server endpoint)

Tags: tcp, netty

I am using camel netty tcp connection to route messages. I used  which appears to be "to" end point as a producer (client mode socket). But my requirement is to make the "to" end point as a server mode socket (server producer) as the messages need to be routed to external clients. Is there a way to do it? If this is not possible, what is the possible solution to this?

Comment: I also wanna to do this. I believe it is necessary to use ChannelHandlerFactories endpoints, as say here >>> http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.camel.user/25656